# Problema em update mysql

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Tenho uma função que realiza um update:

```
function alterarConta(){
     $dataemissao = $_POST['dataemissao'];
     $id = $_POST['id'];
     $select_fornecedores = $_POST['select_fornecedores'];
     $valor = $_POST['valor'];
     $datavencimento = $_POST["datavencimento"];
     $especie = $_POST['especie'];
     $observacao = $_POST['observacao'];
     $banco = abrirBanco();
     $sql = " UPDATE contas SET c.dataemissao = '$dataemissao', c.id_fornecedor = '$select_fornecedores', c.valor = '$valor', c.datavencimento = '$datavencimento', c.especie = '$especie', c.observacao = '$observacao' FROM contas c INNER JOIN pessoa f ON (c.id_fornecedor = f.id) WHERE c.id = '$id'";
    $banco->query($sql);
    $banco->close();

    header('Location: consulta_contas.php');
}
```

Estou com dificuldade, não estou conseguindo encontrar onde está errado.

A estrutura: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é o erro que é exibido? Ou qual é a dificuldade?

Comment: Letícia, de uma olhada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8057585/5429980) para saber como realizar um `UPDATE` com `INNER JOIN` pode lhe ajudar.

Comment: @Everson é possível fazer um UPDATE com INNER JOIN sim.

Comment: Creio que o que o @Everson quis dizer foi que não é possível realizar um UPDATE com FROM.

Comment: @Pantoja isso mesmo, obrigado!

Comment: O erro que é exibido:
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`despesas`.`contas`, CONSTRAINT `contas_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_fornecedor`) REFERENCES `pessoa` (`id`))

Comment: Tentei algo como:
$sql = " UPDATE contas AS c INNER JOIN pessoa AS p ON(c.id_fornecedor = p.id) SET c.dataemissao = '$dataemissao', c.id_fornecedor = '$select_fornecedores', c.valor = '$valor', c.datavencimento = '$datavencimento', c.especie = '$especie', c.observacao = '$observacao' WHERE c.id = '$id' ";

Mas ainda não deu certo. Adicionei uma foto com a estrutura das tabelas

Answer (score 0):

Bem no começo do update substitua `update contas` por `update c`

Depois do `from` você definiu alises para as tabelas e quando tenta realizar a atualização diretamente na tabela o update se perde e tenta atualizar a tabela como um todo.

```
function alterarConta(){
     $dataemissao = $_POST['dataemissao'];
     $id = $_POST['id'];
     $select_fornecedores = $_POST['select_fornecedores'];
     $valor = $_POST['valor'];
     $datavencimento = $_POST["datavencimento"];
     $especie = $_POST['especie'];
     $observacao = $_POST['observacao'];
     $banco = abrirBanco();
     $sql = " UPDATE c SET c.dataemissao = '$dataemissao', c.id_fornecedor = '$select_fornecedores', c.valor = '$valor', c.datavencimento = '$datavencimento', c.especie = '$especie', c.observacao = '$observacao' FROM contas c INNER JOIN pessoa f ON (c.id_fornecedor = f.id) WHERE c.id = '$id'";
    $banco->query($sql);
    $banco->close();

    header('Location: consulta_contas.php');
}
```

Comment: Todo update com multiplas tabelas deve-se fazer referência ao aliase e nao a tabela diretamente.